# How to select the total unique number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say if I want to select total number of unique group which type is 'A' in User table, how can I write the query?

*multiple users may belongs to a same group, there is a field called 'group', another field called 'user type'

Searched on google but didn't find the right one, any answers are welcomed!

Comment: Can you add the actual table structure, and some sample values/output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't terribly clear, but it sounds like you might be after:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT group)
FROM table
WHERE type = 'A'
```

Comment: by the way, if I wanna learn sql server, are there any books you can recommend to me?

Comment: I've heard good things about the Joe's to Pro's series, but I haven't looked through them much.

Answer (score 1):

Without the full design, I have to imply a lot of things.

In this exemple, I suppose that :

- Users have an Id, a Name and that GroupId is the Foreign Key.
- Group has an Id as Primary Key.

This would do it. In that case.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id), username FROM Users
JOIN Groups ON Users.GroupId = Groups.Id
WHERE Users.UserType = 'A'
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: great one! can you recommend any good books on sql server? I'm still a learner and your suggestion is VERY important =]

Comment: There are so many good tutorials that can be found be googling a little. If you get a little more advanced, ones that really help me and that I found interesting are the ones from [Aaron](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand).